# How to run Bayesian A/B testing when your users have a cardinal feature that impacts the treatment set

Tags: bayesian

Suppose you want to run a Bayesian A/B testing to establish whether a certain action influenced conversion rate of your users. What would be the best ways to incorporate the notion that each user has a cardinal feature (e.g. age, average money spent) that impacts the conversion rate when the action is applied (e.g. users in the treatment set that spent more money are more likely to not convert)?

Another example would be the following: you want to check the effect of a drug on curing a condition (cured/not cured) so you give sample a placebo and another the real drug. You also suspect that the age has an impact in curing the condition once the drug is given (e.g. the older you are, the more the the drug has effect in curing the condition).

Is A/B testing the right way to approach this problem or can you suggest any other solutions?
Do you have any suggestion on sources with walk through concrete examples one can utilize to learn more on how to conduct this kind of non-plain scenario with Bayesian techniques?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description could be clearer but it sounds like you're looking to adjust for the fact that the distribution of some relevant covariates (like age) may differ across the two groups (A/B), where you want to compare proportions. If I understand the situation correctly you'd typically use something like logistic regression to deal with that.

Many posts on site discuss logistic regression*, a few discuss the Bayesian version. You might start with a site search, for example.

*(as does Wikipedia and numerous other places on the internet, as well as a great many books)

Comment: based on your feedback I added another use case for this problem and advice on finding sources with walk thought concrete examples one can take a look (I have been searching a bit but could not find a good source for it).
If you want to use logistic regression to see whether the change you introduce had effect, what would be your independent and dependent variables?

Comment: DV is "user converted" (1) or "did not convert" (0). IV is group (A/B = 0/1) + any covariates (and possibly interactions between group and covariates)

Answer (score 2):

[*To address your question change*: I've interpreted your question as using *A/B testing* in the more modern context of real-time testing that attempts to not only *explore* but also to *exploit* what it's learning. Bandits do this. But if you mean that you're going to collect data without acting on it, and then at the end do a batch analysis, `Glen_b`'s answer is better.]

It sounds like you're talking about using a **Beta-Binomial multi-arm bandit** approach to A/B testing where you have a **context** ("cardinal feature"). The simplest way to do that -- assuming there aren't a lot of cardinal features -- would be to have a bandit per cardinal feature class.

You might also look into **Contextual Bandits**, which are more sophisticated (and complicated).

[*To address your comment*: I think the standard *basic* solution is to have *M* *N*-arm bandits for *N* choices, where *M* is the number of different classes (cardinal feature categories) you have. That's the simplest solution, though it would be impractical if you have many cardinal feature classes. (That is, *M* is high, which complicates things computationally and also means some bandits may have very few examples.)]

If you have more than two choices (A/B/C/...) you can use a **Dirichlet-Multinomial** multi-arm bandit.

Comment: Do you mean a bandit with an arm for each feature class and action taken/no action taken? For example if we have button red and button green a cardinal feature with 2 possible values (user usually spending a lot / user usually not spending a lot) there would be 1 bandit with 4 arms.
Or you recommend a bandit for each feature class and one arm for each action?

Comment: Why logistic regression is better than a multi-army bandit approach?

Comment: Bandits are for real-time situations, where you are trading off exploration and exploitation with each sample as it comes in. If you have all of your samples in hand, you can use more flexible/powerful techniques, and logistic regression has nice properties. (And you can do Bayesian logistic regression, including hierarchical logistic regression.)